# PHP MySQL extension missing

Tags: php, mysql, server

I am trying to set up a VPS server on `centos 6` and getting an error `Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.`

When I run `sudo yum install php-mysql`, I get `Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.5.38-7.el6.remi.x86_64`

Can anyone help me please?
thank you

that was stupid,  this worked `sudo yum install php56w-mysql`

Comment: This is because you have the Webtatic repo installed which has newer versions of PHP than the default repos.  Try `yum install php56w-mysql` to install from the right repo.

Answer (score 0):

Before execute install command, run update command first :
    yum update

Comment: then could u try run : ```yum clean all``` then run ```yum update```